# Calculate line integral with respect to arc length

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals, arc-length

Calculate the line integral with respect to arc length of $\int_Czds$, where $C$ is parametrized by $γ(t) = (tcost,tsint,t), 0 ≤ t ≤ t_0.$

I calculate the norm of $γ'(t)$ and I get $\sqrt {2+t^2}$. But how can I calculate $\int_0^{t_0}z \sqrt {2+t^2}dt$? I thought I might did something wrong.

Comment: What is $z$ ? What is $f_C$ ??

Comment: I think $z$ is just a constant. $f_C$ is typo. Sorry. I corrected it.@YvesDaoust

Comment: $z$ is not a constant. Please see value of $z$ in parametrized curve $\gamma(t)$. So replace $z$ with $t$.

Comment: What do you mean value of $z$ in the curve? There's no additional information about relationship with $z$ and $t$. The first line in my question is all I have. @MathLover

Comment: Yes may be the question should have been more clear but that aside, what do you think $t \cos t, t \sin t, t$ in $\gamma(t)$ are?

Comment: Yes may be the question should have been more clear but that aside, what do you think $t \cos t, t \sin t, t$ in $\gamma(t)$ are?

Comment: I think they are components of that parametric curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parametrized curve $C$ is given by $γ(t) = (t \cos t, t \sin t, t), 0 ≤ t ≤ t_0$. What this means is that points on the curve are given by $x = t \cos t, y = t \sin t, z = t$.

So the integral of scalar function $f(x, y, z) = z$ with respect to arc length,

$\displaystyle \int_C z \ ds = \int_0^{t_0} t \ \gamma'(t) \ dt = \int_0^{t_0} t \ \sqrt{2+t^2} \ dt$